# Google App Engine File Upload Canceled

Tags: java, google-app-engine, gwt, file-upload

[Google App Engine documentation](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/quotas#Requests) says that there is a 32MB limit by HTTP request.

I'm trying to upload a 44K file, but I get a "Canceled" status without any references of what happened on server log (it works on dev environment). When I give a shot with a 7.5K file (7.8K request) everything works fine.

I just need to parse this file and return a response to the client, so I don't need Blobstore API to save it.

Below, my client (GWT) code:

```
    form.setAction("/import_file_parser");
    form.setEncoding(FormPanel.ENCODING_MULTIPART);
    form.setMethod(FormPanel.METHOD_POST);
    form.addSubmitCompleteHandler(uploadReceiver);
```

Is this 32MB limit still valid? What is happening?

Comment: Is your 44K file taking a bit longer than like 30/60 seconds?

Comment: It takes a few seconds (5) on my local machine. Furthermore, request it's not getting GAE production servers, because I don't see it logged.

Comment: Maybe you can first check what is actually happening by using Chrome dev tools or something like that?

Comment: @vishal.biyani The 60 second execution limit does not apply to upload and download time in any case.